# Heights of multiples of rational points on elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, limits-and-convergence, rational-points, heights

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve, given by some minimal Weierstrass equation (say $Y^2 = X^3 + aX + b$ for some integer $a$ and $b$), and let $P$ be a rational point on $E$ which is not the infinite point. We assume that $P$ is not torsion.

The point $P$ can be written as $(\frac{x}{d^2}, \frac{y}{d^3})$ for some integers $x, y, d$ such that $d$ is prime to $x$ and $y$.

Now consider the sequence of points $P, 2P, 3P, \cdots$, we are led to three sequences $x_n, y_n, d_n$, such that $nP = (\frac{x_n}{d_n^2}, \frac{y_n}{d_n^3})$.

The question: does the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{2\log(d_n)}{n^2}$ exist? Is it equal to the canonical height of $P$?

Same question for $x_n$ and $y_n$?

---

A related question:

Let us denote by $h(P)$ the natural height of $P$, i.e. $h(P) = \log(\max\{|x|, |d^2|\})$. Does the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{h(nP)}{n^2}$ exist? (If it exists, then it of course is equal to the canonical height.)

Comment: The answer to the second question is YES, and is certainly explained in books on elliptic curves such as Joe Silverman's : the canonical height of $P$, $\hat h(P)$, is the limit of $h(x(nP))/n^2$, when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @ACL Could you tell me where in the book of Silverman is this result stated? The canonical height, by definition, is the limit of $h(2^n P)/4^n$, which is different from what you write. Besides, his Corollary 6.4 of Chapter VIII has a big O constant that depends on $m$.

Comment: There is a uniform bound for $h(P)-\hat h(P)$; apply it to the point nP and use that $\hat h(nP)=n^2\hat h(P)$.

Comment: @ACL You are right. I just figured it out myself. Do you have idea for the denominator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use Siegel's theorem (which is quite deep and relies on Roth's theorem or some such). This is in Chapter IX of *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, specifically Theoream IX.3.1. You'll need to unsort the definitions a bit, since it's stated for number fields, but in your notation, one has
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2\log d_n}{n^2}
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log |x_n|}{n^2}
= \hat h(P).
$$
Hmmm.. Actually, the definitions are unsorted for you in Example IX.3.3, where you'll find the following formula (using your notation) in the middle of page 279 (of the 2nd edition):
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log|x_n|}{\log d_n^2} = 1. $$

BTW, the sequence $(d_n)_{n\ge1}$ is called the *Elliptic Divisibility Sequence* associated to the curve $E$ and point $P$. The fact that $\log d_n$ grows like a multiple of $n^2$ is an essential fact used to prove that elliptic divisibility sequences satisfy the Zsigmondy property: for all but finitely many $n$, there is a prime $p$ such that $p\mid d_n$ and $p\nmid d_m$ for all $m < n$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is now clear to me that the problem has something essential to do with diophantine approximations. The question I have in mind is the following: given a bound $M$, is it possible to determine all the $n$ such that $nP$ has denominator smaller than $M$? Of course the effective method of Baker gives a theoretical "Yes" answer, but since the expected number of $n$ is just $\sqrt(\log(M))$, I wonder if this can be done simpler, by proving e.g. that the sequence $d_n$ is strictly increasing for $n$ larger than an effectively computable bound.

Comment: @WhatsUp Do you want to determine all $n$, or do you want to bound the number of such $n$? The latter can be done, since there are effective qualitative versions of Roth's theorem. In other words, I think that one can find an (effective) constant $C=C(E,P)$ so that for all $M\ge2$, $$\#\{n : d(nP)\le M\} \le C\sqrt{\log M}.$$ This should follow from the results in my paper "A quantitative version of Siegel's theorem", *J. Reine Angew. Math.* **378** (1987), 60-100.

Comment: My principle aim is actually to effectively **determine** all such $n$, for a big bound like $M = 1e6$. Is it possible, or something known to be hard? But this effective bound on the number also looks interesting to me!